# Hiding Text after icon using CSS

Tags: css

How can I hide the text after the font awesome icon using CSS without having to put it in a span.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.4/css/all.css">

<li class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link" href="opt-categories.php">
    <i class="fa fa-truck"></i>
    Food Categories
  </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Set the font size for entire link text to 0:

```
.nav-link { font-size: 0; }
```

then revert that property, for the icon only:

```
.nav-link .fa { font-size: initial; }
```

Other option would be to make text just invisible e.g.  `color: transparent;` for the link and `color: black;` for the icon only.

Answer (score 0):

`visibility: hidden` seems to work well

```css
.nav-link {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.nav-link i {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.4/css/all.css">

<li class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link" href="opt-categories.php">
    <i class="fa fa-truck"></i>
    Food Categories
  </a>
</li>
```